# Loading a background fragment and sharing between two activites

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Do fragment exist only in the activity they are created? What I am trying to do is I have a splashactivity.java and mainactivity.java and a BackgroundDataFragment.java I am creating the BackgroundDataFragment in splashactivity and then moving to mainactivity but can't find the loaded BackgroundDataFragment there. The call

```
mBackgroundFragment = (BackgroundDataFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());
```

always return BackgroundDataFragment as null in mainactivity.java. I

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    /**
     * The data fragment.
     */
    protected BackgroundDataFragment mBackgroundFragment;
}
```

splashactivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private BroadcastReceiver mAppStatusBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String status = intent.getStringExtra(BundleTags.APP_DATA_STATUS.name());
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(status) && "loading".equals(status)) {
             showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.loading_progress_app), getSupportFragmentManager());
            } else {
                dismissProgressDialog(getSupportFragmentManager());
                loadDataAndStartMainActivity();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        if (mBackgroundFragment == null) {
            mBackgroundFragment = (BackgroundDataFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());
            if (mBackgroundFragment == null) {
                DialogHelper.showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.loading_progress_app), getSupportFragmentManager());
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                mBackgroundFragment = new BackgroundDataFragment();
                transaction.add(mBackgroundFragment, FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());
                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadDataAndStartMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        // close this activity
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mAppStatusBroadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(PreferencesKey.APP_DATA_STATUS));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mAppStatusBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity  {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (mBackgroundFragment == null) {

        // This call always return BackgroundDataFragment as null
        mBackgroundFragment = (BackgroundDataFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());

        if (mBackgroundFragment != null) {
            //setup view for the page etc
        }
    } else {
        //setup view for the page etc
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats your intention to do so?

Comment: Intention is load all the data for the app to use and while doing so show a nice splash screen and progressbar. once all data is loaded pass it to the other activity which has all the fragments that will use this data. The data I am storing in a non-ui data fragment so that other fragments etc can add/update/delete the state of date through standard notify/listener pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a Fragment between 2 activities because each activity has it's own FragmentManager. To share data between 2 activities, you can use Bundle, or store data in Application object.

Comment: you are correct! This is a conceptual thing. That is how fragments are designed to stay in the lifecycle of the activity that created it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't share fragment between two activities. findFragmentByTag will try to find fragment by its tag if its in xml or added to activity by transaction. Also one thing to note is that you have called finish() so acitivity will be destroyed and fragment's lifecycle depends on activity so it will also get destroyed.

You can load your data and put in bundle and then pass it through intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("key2",parcelableObject);
intent.putExtra("key1",bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You are also correct. You can share any data as long as it is Parcelable. With Fragments you can get a SavedState which is a parcelable object and you can use that to reconstruct the Fragment in other activity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rey Pham and @Damanpreet Singh. Yes the fragment belongs to the activity's fragment manager and hence can't be shared through fragmentmanager. The workaround I found is to save the state of fragment and then pass that in the bundle and eventually recreate it form the saved state in another activity. I think this is a very useful approach for expensive Fragments. Although I think we should avoid doing such thing unless absolutely necessary. E.g. my objective here is to load application data into background fragment and show splash screen untill it loads then move to main activity where other fragments will use this. I need to read more about DataLoaders etc to see may be there is a better way to share app related data among fragments etc without using a non-ui background fragment.

splashactivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        Fragment.SavedState savedState = getSupportFragmentManager().saveFragmentInstanceState(mBackgroundFragment);
        intent.putExtra(FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name(), savedState);
        startActivity(intent);
        // close this splashactivity
        finish();
```

mainactivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mBackgroundFragment = new DataFragment();
            Fragment.SavedState backgroundFragmentState = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());
            mBackgroundFragment.setInitialSavedState(backgroundFragmentState);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(mBackgroundFragment, FragmentTags.FRAGMENT_DATA_TAG.name());
            transaction.commit();
    }
```